# Make Log File Highlighter VS Code extension works with long files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the VS Code extension [LogFileHighlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emilast.LogFileHighlighter) for adding color highlighting to log files. But when I try to open a long file log (around 20k lines) the extension doesn't add the color highlighting.

I can only see the highlighting with small files. Is there any configuration to change the file size limit for highlighting or another way to make work for long files?

Comment: How is the performance, after appyling this setting?

Comment: Is a bit more slowly than without the setting but the performance is ok. I'm managing a log file with 400k lines and is really manageable, even you can "Find" without performance problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `"editor.largeFileOptimizations" : false`
this shoud remove limitations.

Answer (score 3):

As said above but disable it for log files specifically (in "settings.json"):

```
"[log]": {
    "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false
}
```